# How can I change the label for the vote button?

Tags: 7, polls

I am using poll module in my site. Everything is working fine. But the submit button(label) is "vote", I want to change it to "Submit". How can i change this? And this is a block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement `hook_form_alter()` for altering the *poll_view_voting* form and change `#value` from *Vote* to *Submit*.

```
function mymodule_form_poll_view_voting_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['vote']['#value'] = t('Submit');
}
```